# Git (DVCS) pull/fetch update/merge

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to understand Git and I've come across countless variations of the image below.

[pull update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81k8V.png)

But as I studied more, it seems to me that what is called a "pull" in the image (copy from a remote repository to a local repository) should be the "fetch", and what is called an "update" (LR to a working branch) in the image should be the "merge". (Pull is then a fetch + merge.)

Or am I missing something?
Thank you.